# Is there a way to find a value in an Excel spreadsheet and colour the cell?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I'm currently using OpenXML to read an excel spreadsheet into a data grid, then pass it through some basic validation for the Strings, datetimes & ints etc based on the Object Models (Im also using MVVM). These failures are then output to a list of errors.

Rather than display the validation errors on screen, the stakeholders would prefer to have the initial Excel spreadsheet amended/updated to show where the failures occur (colour the cell). The user can then change that highlighted value to a correct one.

I have found various ways to find the cell value from the address, but not to find cell based on the value. Is this possible using OpenXML (or even ClosedXML) and avoiding the Interop Library?

Any reference material or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: But if you are reading the Excel with OpenXML you already read the cells, so you know if the value in that cell is valid or not. Anyway:  You could call Descendants<Cell> on a Sheet: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.openxmlelement.descendants?view=openxml-2.8.1#documentformat-openxml-openxmlelement-descendants-1 to get a collection of cells and then do a Where( cell=> cell.Text == "42") or something that matches the actual cellType value of the cells you're interested in.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look a that. I'm fairly new to OpenXml and am not sure what its all doing yet.